# How can i return tree traversal as an array from a C function

Tags: c, data-structures, tree-traversal

I can in-order traverse a tree with the below code. But if want to return the in-order traversal from this function how can i do that?

```
void inorder(Node* root){
    if(root==NULL){
        return;
    }
    inorder(root->left);
    printf("%d\n",root->data);
    inorder(root->right);
}
```

Comment: So you want an an array of `Node*`?

Comment: you can pass as an argument a pointer to a structure with `array` and actual item `id` starting from 0, this way you can both update the array and increment the id: `arr[id++] = root->data` . Make sure your array has enough size for this, e.g. allocate it based on tree size.

Comment: @pbn A little more help highly appreciated :)

Comment: @Michael Walz just an array of `node->data`

Comment: @MDXF So am i being coerced to read your articles else you downvote my question?

Answer (score -1):

```
void inorder(Node* root,int str[])
{
     static int i=0;
     if(root==Null){
         return;
     }
    inorder(root->left,str);
    str[i++] = root->data;
    inorder(root->right,str);
    str[i] = SOME_SENTINEL_VALUE 
}
int * inorder_temp(Node *root)
{
    int *str=(int*)malloc(MAX_SIZE_OF_TREE*sizeof(int));
    inorder(root,str);
    return str;
}
```

I hope this is what you are asking.Call inorder_temp() in place of inorder()
Edit: Sorry for not indenting properly.This is my first answer at stackoverflow

Comment: Please submit at least indented code. -1 for  not indenting. I will remove the downvote once it is indented. And this answer is somewhat minimalist.